# Declaring constants in Python

Tags: variables, constants, keyword

Is it possible to define a constant in Python using any specific keyword? Or it is just in a way that we declare a variable and use it without its value changed as if it is a constant?

Since I am a beginner to Python, I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no as such keyword to declare constant in python

But while defining constant in python it should be in upper case.

It's Recommended by python

> language = 'python' ------> this is variable
>
> LANGUAGE = 'python' -----> this is constant